# Delete Document from SharePoint Document list, using Lists.asmx, just by ID

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am looking for a solution to just a pass a Item Id to delete the documents, without passing FileRef parameter.

will appreciate any help?

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

UpdateListItems will do what you want:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems(v=office.12).aspx

For the xml block you will want something like this to delete item id=1234:

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1" >
<Method ID="1" Cmd="Delete">
  <Field Name="ID">1234<Field>
</Method>
</Batch>
```